# Things to do to port game made for iOS in Unity to Android?

Tags: c#, android, unity, ios

I have just made my first game for iOS and submitted it to app store. I was thinking of porting my game to Android also. I would like to know things one need to do/remember to port game made for iOS in Unity to Android. How to handle different screen resolutions and pixel densities, optimizations required, etc. Any other suggestions and important things you think I should know?

EDIT:
Also, should I handle builds according to device resolutions or by pixel density?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all very game specific.

It all depends on how *your game* handles its UI and the size of things on screen to determine how you're going to solve the pixel density and resolution disparity issues (which should be pretty similar to how you're solving iPad vs iPhone, assuming you are).

Any optimizations you're doing for the iOS version should apply to the Android version.  You really just need to get a couple of target devices and test on them.

As for specifics, if you're *not* using OpenGLES 2.0 and you are doing fixed function shader stuff you need to realize that you have fewer texture stages on Android hardware than on iOS hardware.  It's generally 2 instead of 4 I think.

One thing that Android users are used to that you'll have to add is soft "back" button support.  Basically check for `KeyCode.Escape` and go "back" where appropriate.  I think this also includes exiting the application if you're, for example, on the main menu.

Comment: Thanks again @Tetrad for reply! I'm already halfway with iPad thing. I'm using OpenGLES 2.0 so there should not be any problem there. So next step should be getting different resolution android devices for testing and adding back button support. :D